# Connecting local Spyder IDE (on Windows) to remote kernel on Google Cloud

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, spyder, remote-access

I have followed the instructions [here](https://medium.com/@halmubarak/connecting-spyder-ide-to-a-remote-ipython-kernel-25a322f2b2be):
(including the paramiko packgage).

The putty connection works.
I have also downloaded the kernel `.json` file from the **VM**.
Into Spyder I go:

1. Consoles / Connect to existing kernel
2. Point toward the .json file (located in the local /jupyter/runtime folder)
3. Check this is a remote kernel
4. username@location:port (same as in Putty connection)
5. Enter the remote user password
6. Ok ...

Connecting to kernel ....

Appears in the Ipython console.  And spins and spins.   No timeout, nothing.